# How can i list of common posts of the two categories in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Headline Category..Im using this category in sidebar widget of all Category page.

I want this, When i in a category (Example: Internet Category), my Headline widget list Headline and Current Cat (Example: Internet Category) common Last 5 post

Example Pictures : [LINK](http://content.screencast.com/users/genxer/folders/Question%20Screenshot/media/7ccac66b-e92f-49c6-b5e4-27d70fc9fce1/question_5.jpg)

I want to list common post Headline and Current Category

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty minimal but I think this is what you want.

```
$args = array(
  'category__and' => array($cat1,$cat2),
  'posts_per_page' => 5
);
$common = new WP_Query($args);
```

You need to pass the category IDs of the categories you want to [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) on this line: `'category__and' => array($cat1,$cat2)`. That should require posts to be in both categories. you may need to add other key/values to `$args` to fine tune the results. See the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).